# Filter in pandas a DataFrame where a column value has been repeated exactly a certain number of cases

Tags: python, pandas

For example if I have a DataFrame of people_ids and their dogs, where if a person has two dogs it appears twice, each with a different dog, and I want to find exactly the people who have two or three dogs.

I would use some code like:

```
df[df.col.isin(df.col.value_counts()[df.col.value_counts()==2].index)]
```

however this seems awfully convoluted, i have to reference the DataFrame four times and run the value_counts function twice.

Any ideas that might help this be a bit more simple and straightforward?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pandas isn't always amenable to one-liners. Fortunately we have the rest of the Python language to help us. I assume your data is organized such that `dog_id` is the index, and `person_id` is one of the data columns.

```py
dogs_per_person = data['person_id'].value_counts()
person_ids = dogs_per_person.loc[dogs_per_person.isin({2, 3})].index
data.loc[data['person_id'].isin(person_ids)]
```

So the answer is: no, not really. But at least you can make the code a little easier to read, and sometimes more CPU-efficient, by assigning things to variables and re-using those variables.

You could write a helper function to do the "self-filtering" operation, which might be appealing:

```py
from operator import methodcaller

def filter_values_series(series, fn):
    return series.loc[fn(series)]

dogs_per_person = data['person_id'].value_counts()
person_ids = filter_values(person_ids, methodcaller('isin', {2, 3})).index
data.loc[data['person_id'].isin(person_ids)]
```

Unfortunately, the elegant constructions you find in R (and particularly in third-party libraries like Dplyr and Data.Table) are impossible to implement in Python due to the more restricted nature of the language engine and syntax. The tradeoff is that stricter discipline is enforced on the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, using [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df[df.groupby("col").col.transform('size').isin((2,3))]]
```